# Quadratic Recurrence $a_{n+1} = 4a_n - 4a_n^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, contest-math, functional-equations, sequence-of-function

How do I solve this quadratic recurrence $a_{n+1} = 4a_n - 4a_n^2$?

Actually, it came from $f(x) = 4x(1-x)$ when $f : [0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$.

The problem asked about number of distinct roots of $f^{1992}(x)$=x. I do know that there are $2^{1992}$ roots. But , I don’t know how to cancel the repeated roots.

I tried set $a_n = f(a_{n - 1})$ and $a_1$ = $c$.

Which gives the quadratic recurrence $a_{n+1} = 4a_n - 4a_n^2$. But , I don’t know how to solve it.

Edit : If this recurrence can’t be solved , I tried put $x = sin^2(x)$ and it yields $f(sin^2(x)) = sin^2(2x)$!

Edit 2: $f^n(x) = f(f^{n-1}(x))$.

Comment: @Teerapat_Math Why do you say there are repeated roots?

Comment: I am not sure about it.

Comment: I think it may have repeated roots.

Comment: In general you can't really solve it, I believe.

Comment: So , how can I solve this FE?

Comment: If $x = sin^2(x)$ , then , $f(x) = sin^2(2x)$

Comment: @Teerapat_Math In the quadratic example you mentioned, I think the roots are distinct and can be computed. Not sure on the process, but I remember this from some discrete dynamical systems (and symbolic dynamics) courses I took many years ago.

Comment: What do you mean by "solve the recurrence" ? Find a closed-form expression ? Determine when the sequence converges ?

Comment: So , if I solve this without recurrence , can anyone gives me some hint?

Comment: I think of putting x = $sin^2(x)$. But I still can’t solve it.

Comment: Would proving that there are no repeated root solve your question ?

Comment: Can anyone check if I’m right or wrong?

Comment: I put $x = sin^2(x)$. After computing $f^{1992}(x)$, I get $f^{1992}(x) = sin^2(3984x)$. So, in eq. $x = f^{1992}(x)$    
have only one roots. Since $x = sin^2(3984x)$.

Comment: This is called [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map#Solution_when_r_=_4).

Comment: Thank you. @rtybase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_n=\sin^2(b_n)$ to make
$$\cos (2 b_{n+1})=\cos (4 b_n)\implies b_n=2^{n-1} C\implies a_n=???$$